# Could Somebody explain this error (regarding framents)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm new to android development, I'm using fragments in my application with a single activity, it is working fine, but the only problem I have is when I try to return to first fragment on clicking a button it is giving me this error, I could able to figure it out, searched on stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: Why did you edit out the logcat trace? As it currently stands, the question is not helpful to anyone. To make it better, include both exception info and code that causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eror happens if you have a parent View and you add 2 Views to it. For example if the parent View is a scrollLayout, an exception like this will be thrown.

That happens because a ScrollView is supposed to have only one Child View.

If you add your Code, i might be able to tell you how to resolve the issue.